# Problem double borders in primereact datatable

Tags: javascript, datatable, scrollable, primereact

I'm using datatable component from primereact. I have a double borders problem with a scrollable talbe.

Here is the sandbox example : https://codesandbox.io/s/primereact-demo-forked-emfgtk?file=/src/App.js

As you can see in browser part, bottom border in header are thicker.

I would like to have simple borders

Comment: On Chrome, no ticker borders are shown. Have you tried other browsers?

Comment: There is, also on chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you have a border-bottom and border-top, basically doubling the border width.

The cleanest solution would be to add `border-collapse: collapse` to the `table` itself. You can read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse?retiredLocale=de).

One solution is to add the following style:

```
.p-datatable.p-datatable-gridlines .p-datatable-thead > tr:not(:first-of-type) > th {
    border-top: 0;
}
```

Which basically removes the top-border on all Table-Headers which are not in the first row.